# How to put place holder for video loading on pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a video in a page. However, when the page loads, it displays everything and then right at the end the video all of a sudden appears taking up space. Is it possible to atleast put a placeholder there while page loads aka I do not want video to suddenly appear.. I need some kind of placeholder or loading thing so that user experience is enhanced

Comment: It is not like it is not working.. I am just not sure how to add a placeholder for videos (Ooyala player)...I can give you the Ooyala player code.. I do not think that will help either. Again http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/api/player_v3_api_embedparams.html is the doco for that.Any tips or hints on how to do this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS to set the height and width to the size of the video for your `playerCtn` container:

`<div id="playerCtn" class="module">`

Like:

`#playerCtn {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px; 
}`